# How do I update a field in the array of struct in BQ?

Tags: google-bigquery

In the example, I can update the field "name", but I'm not able to update the field "city" in the array of struct.

```
--create or replace table mydataset.struct_3 (name string,address array< struct<status string, city string,state string>>)
--insert into mydataset.struct_3 (name,address) values("some_name",[("previous","some_city","some_state"),("current","some_city","some_state")])
--update `mydataset.struct_3` set name="some_name2" where name="some_name"
update  `mydataset.struct_3` set address.city="some_uscity" where address.city="some_city"
```

I get this error,

```
Error: Cannot access field city on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<status STRING, city STRING, state STRING>> at [4:75]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the array itself, updating the desired value:

```
update  `mydataset.struct_3`
set address = ARRAY(SELECT IF(city="some_city", "some_uscity", city) FROM UNNEST(address))
```

Answer (score 4):

```sql
#standardSQL
UPDATE `mydataset.struct_3` SET address = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT 
    status, IF(city="some_city", "some_uscity", city) city, state 
  FROM UNNEST(address)
) WHERE TRUE
```