# BigQuery - Data Manipulation Language and Nested Columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working a lot with nested columns (Type Record, Mode Repeated).
It happens that I would like to DELETE or UPDATE rows where conditions in the nested rows are met.
Besides that, it could happen that I want to UPDATE or DELETE the values within the nested rows.

So far this seems to be impossible because I cannot UPDATE/DELETE from a cross-join that I generate with UNNEST..
I wasn't able to find a direct solution to that on StackOverflow or in the Google Docs, except using SELECT to create a new table that contains everything except the rows to be deleted.
But even with the SELECT workaround, I wouldn't know how to do that when I want to change the values within nested fields.
I have tried only with Standard SQL so far and no experience with Legacy SQL.

Comment: there are many questions like this one - with answers here on SO, so you just need search better! or if you have some extremely special case  -you should outline it - otherwise it is a duplicate or too broad!

Comment: another ones - https://stackoverflow.com/q/44907954/5221944 ; https://stackoverflow.com/q/50642028/5221944 - but there are really more of such